# Make command is failing when I clean

Tags: c, makefile

I am a beginner and I have made a simple make file:

```
build:
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 ./src/*.c -o game

run:
    ./game

clean:
    rm game
```

I can run `make build` and `make run` but I'm getting an error for `make clean`:

```
PS C:\Users\anton\game> make build
gcc -Wall -std=c99 ./src/*.c -o game
PS C:\Users\anton\game> make run
./game
Game is running...
PS C:\Users\anton\game> make clean
rm game
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm game, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:8: clean] Error 2
```

I already made sure the MinGW bin folder is in the PATH system variable and there are no other bin directories there. I do not know where is the issue?

Comment: Use `rm -f`.  Or, at a pinch, add a dash `-` before `rm`.

Comment: "Where the issue is" -- `rm a-thing-that-does-not-exist` fails. `rm` only succeeds when it's successfully able to unlink the names passed as arguments.

Comment: This isn't a problem with `rm` not finding the file, it's a problem with `CreateProcess` failing because it can't find the `rm` command. Was the `bin` directory in the `PATH` before you started the shell? Have you looked in the `bin` directory for the `rm` command? Have you tried doing `rm game` yourself in the shell? It was some time since I used MinGW, but perhaps there are multiple `bin` directories?

Comment: In PowerShell `rm` is an alias for `Remove-Item`. That may be the issue. `del` is also an alias.

Comment: Thank you for the comments the rm command was not recognized so I just use del and it worked thank you for the help.

Comment: Just to mention: make never uses powershell (unless you force it to by adding a setting in your makefile).  Make will always use a POSIX shell, if found, or if not found (on Windows) it will fall back to cmd.exe.  The shell make uses has no relationship to the shell that the _user_ uses when they run `make`.  That would be crazy from a portability standpoint.